# How can I instruct Json.NET to convert an interface type to a concrete type without access to the serializer?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

My problem is that I need to deserialize JSON to a type that in turn contains interface type objects, and thus am required to instruct Json.NET on how to convert that interface type, but am not in control of the `Newtonsoft.Json.Deserializer` directly. The deserialization is handled indirectly by framework code, i.e. by [HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

How can I specify a conversion from the interface type to a concrete type, without being able to add a converter to `JsonSerializer.Converters` directly? If I use the `[JsonConverter]` attribute on the interface definition, the converter also gets called for implementations of the interface (i.e., the concrete type I'm converting to).

The below code shows a C# console program that attempts to deserialize the same JSON to first the `Parent2` class and then the `Parent1` class, instructing Json.NET to convert the `IChild1` interface type to the `Child1` concrete type via `JsonConverterAttribute`. The deserialization to `Parent2` works since I add `ChildConverter` directly to `serializer.Converters`, whereas deserializing to `Parent1` results in a stack overflow exception, due to `ChildConverter.Deserialize` being called even for the `Child1` type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace TestConsole
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ChildConverter))]
    interface IChild1
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Child1 : IChild1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Parent1
    {
        public IEnumerable<IChild1> Children { get; set; }
    }

    interface IChild2
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Child2 : IChild2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Parent2
    {
        public IEnumerable<IChild2> Children { get; set; }
    }

    class ChildConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(IChild1) || objectType == typeof(IChild2);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (objectType == typeof(IChild1))
                return serializer.Deserialize<Child1>(reader);
            return serializer.Deserialize<Child2>(reader);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{'Children': [{'Name': 'Child1'}, {'Name': 'Child2'}]}";

            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            serializer.Converters.Add(new ChildConverter());
            var obj = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(json), typeof(Parent2));

            serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(json), typeof(Parent1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my particular problem, being to call [HttpContent.ReadAsAsync<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and have that deserialize a JSON response. While my solution doesn't resolve the general problem of configuring Json.NET type conversion without access to the serializer, it does resolve my particular problem. What I found is that `HttpContent.ReadAsync<T>` accepts an `IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter>`, that is used to deserialize the response. Here one can pass a `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, which has been configured with your `JsonConverter` of choice (in my example, `ChildConverter`).

```
var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
formatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ChildConverter());
var obj = await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(new MediaTypeFormatter[] {formatter});
```